# Alterar cor de input em página HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Estou desenvolvendo uma página simples em **HTML** com **JavaScript** também.

Porém estou com um problema, em minha página quando um dado é preenchido de maneira incorreta, aparece um `alert` e a cor do `input` muda para vermelho, quando o dado for preenchido corretamente a cor do `input` deveria voltar para o padrão, porém isso não acontece.

Como posso resolver este problema?? SÓ PODE SER UTILIZADO HTML E JS

```js
<script>
function Cadastrar() {

    var re_nome = /^[A-Za-záàâãéèêíïóôõöúçñÁÀÂÃÉÈÍÏÓÔÕÖÚÇÑ ]+$/;
    var re_email = /^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+@([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+\.)[a-zA-Z-0-9]{2,3}$/;
    var re_nasci = /^([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})$/;
    var re_cpf = /^([\d]{3})([\d]{3})([\d]{3})([\d]{2})$/;

    if (re_nome.test(nome.value) && re_email.test(email.value) && re_nasci.test(nasci.value) && re_cpf.test(cpf.value)) {
        var table = document.getElementById("tabela");
        var row = tabela.insertRow(1);
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
        var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
        var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
        var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
        var cell7 = row.insertCell(6);

        row.appendChild(cell1);
        row.appendChild(cell2);
        row.appendChild(cell3);
        row.appendChild(cell4);
        row.appendChild(cell5);
        row.appendChild(cell6);
        row.appendChild(cell7);

        cell1.innerHTML = nome.value;
        cell2.innerHTML = email.value;
        cell3.innerHTML = nasci.value.replace(re_nasci, "$1/$2/$3");
        cell4.innerHTML = cpf.value.replace(re_cpf, "$1.$2.$3-$4");
        cell5.innerHTML = cidade.value;
        cell6.innerHTML = estado.value;
        cell7.innerHTML = endereco.value;
        //return Limpar();
    }

    if (!re_nome.test(nome.value)) {
        alert("O campo NOME esta incorreto");
        var txtInc =
                document.getElementById("nome").style.borderColor = "#FF0000";
    }

    if (!re_email.test(email.value)) {
        alert("O campo EMAIL esta incorreto");
        var txtInc =
                document.getElementById("email").style.borderColor = "#FF0000";
    }
    alert("slaa");

    if (!re_nasci.test(nasci.value)) {
        alert("O campo NASCI esta incorreto");
        var txtInc = document.getElementById("nasci").style.borderColor = "#FF0000";
    }

    if (!re_cpf.test(cpf.value)) {
        alert("O campo CPF esta incorreto");
        var txtInc = document.getElementById("cpf").style.borderColor = "#FF0000";
    }
}

function Limpar() {
    document.getElementById("form1").reset();
}
</script>
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Cadastro de Contatos </title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Newcontatos.js"></script>
</head>
<body bgcolor="WHITE">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><img src="img/tel.png" height="50" width="50"/></td>
            <td><p>Cadastro de contatos</p><br></td>
        </tr>
    </table><br><br>
    <form id="form1">
        <label for="nome">Nome*:</label>
        <input id="nome" type="text" maxlength="50" name="nome"/><br><br><br>

        <label for="email">E-mail*:</label>
        <input id="email" type="text" name="email"/><br><br><br>

        <label for="nasci">Data Nascimento*:</label>
        <input id="nasci" type="date" name="nasci" min="1900-01-01" max="2019-06-30"/><br><br><br>

        <label for="cpf">CPF*:</label>
        <input id="cpf" value="11122233355" maxlength="11" type="int" name="cpf"/><label>(xxx.xxx.xxx-xx)</label><br><br><br>

        <label for="cidade">Cidade:</label>
        <input id="cidade" type="text" name="cidade"/><br><br><br>

        <label for="estado">Estado:</label>
        <select for="estado" type="int" name="estado">
            <option>Selecione</option>
            <option>AC</option>
            <option>AL</option>
            <option>...</option>
        </select><br><br><br>

        <label for="endereco">Endereco:</label>
        <input id="endereco" type="text" name="endereco"/><br><br><br>
    </form>

    <button width=35 height=25 title="Cadastrar" onclick="Cadastrar()">Cadastrar</button>
    <button width=35 height=25 title="Limpar" onclick="Limpar()">Limpar</button><br><br>

    <hr><br><br><br>

    <table id="tabela" width="400" border="1" align="left">
        <tr bgcolor="ff6600">
            <td>Nome:</td>
            <td>Email:</td>
            <td>Data Nascimento:</td>
            <td>CPF:</td>
            <td>Cidade:</td>
            <td>Estado:</td>
            <td>Endereco:</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Faz um else em todos os ifs com document.getElementById("cpf").style.borderColor="#FFFFFF"; Tem maneiras mais bonitas para resolver, mas essa funciona bem

Comment: Olha eu creio já ter tentado várias coisas semelhantes, mas essa em específico não me recordo, muito obrigado :) Tentei e acabou não dando certo, bom, vou procurar outras maneiras

Comment: O que pode ser feito ao invés de utilizar o button cadastrar, utilizar jquery quando o campo mudar ele executa a função e verifica se os campos estão corretos

Comment: Quer a validação apenas quando clicam em Cadastrar? 
Ou depois do utilizador preencher o campo?

Comment: @MauroAlmeida sim, isso mesmo

Comment: Isso mesmo que parte? Eu fiz 2 perguntas :-|

Comment: @AndreLacomski tinha até esquecido, só posso utilizar js, até já editei a pergunta colocando este detalhe

Comment: @MauroAlmeida clicando em cadastrar -.-

Comment: Para voltar a cor padrão do navegador é só esvaziar a propriedade borderColor em um else: `document.getElementById("nome").style.borderColor="";`

Answer (score -1):

Par alterar a cor da borda novamente, você pode utilizar else e aplicar a mesma cor ou até pintar de verde, por exemplo, para mostrar que está correto.

**No código abaixo, coloquei no nome como exemplo**

```js
function Cadastrar(){
 
 var re_nome = /^[A-Za-záàâãéèêíïóôõöúçñÁÀÂÃÉÈÍÏÓÔÕÖÚÇÑ ]+$/; 
 var re_email = /^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+@([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+\.)[a-zA-Z-0-9]{2,3}$/;
 var re_nasci = /^([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})$/;   
 var re_cpf = /^([\d]{3})([\d]{3})([\d]{3})([\d]{2})$/;
 
 if(re_nome.test(nome.value) && re_email.test(email.value) && re_nasci.test(nasci.value) && re_cpf.test(cpf.value)){
  var table = document.getElementById("tabela");
  var row = tabela.insertRow(1);
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
  var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
  var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
  var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
  var cell7 = row.insertCell(6);
  
  row.appendChild(cell1);
  row.appendChild(cell2);
  row.appendChild(cell3);
  row.appendChild(cell4);
  row.appendChild(cell5);
  row.appendChild(cell6);
  row.appendChild(cell7);
  
  cell1.innerHTML = nome.value;
  cell2.innerHTML = email.value;
  cell3.innerHTML = nasci.value.replace(re_nasci, "$1/$2/$3");
  cell4.innerHTML = cpf.value.replace(re_cpf, "$1.$2.$3-$4");
  cell5.innerHTML = cidade.value;
  cell6.innerHTML = estado.value;
  cell7.innerHTML = endereco.value;
  //return Limpar();
 }
 
 if(!re_nome.test(nome.value)){
  alert("O campo NOME esta incorreto");
  var txtInc = 
        document.getElementById("nome").style.borderColor="#FF0000";
 }
  else {
        document.getElementById("nome").style.border = '1px solid #999';
  }
  
 if(!re_email.test(email.value)){
  alert("O campo EMAIL esta incorreto");
  var txtInc = 
        document.getElementById("email").style.borderColor="#FF0000"; 
 }alert("slaa");
  
 if(!re_nasci.test(nasci.value)){
  alert("O campo NASCI esta incorreto");
  var txtInc = document.getElementById("nasci").style.borderColor="#FF0000"; 
 }
  
 if(!re_cpf.test(cpf.value)){
  alert("O campo CPF esta incorreto");
  var txtInc = document.getElementById("cpf").style.borderColor="#FF0000"; 
 }
    }
    
    function Limpar(){
     document.getElementById("form1").reset(); 
    }
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Cadastro de Contatos </title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Newcontatos.js"></script>
 </head>
 
 <body bgcolor="WHITE">
  <table>
   <tr>
    <td><img src="img/tel.png" height="50" width="50"/></td>
    <td><p>Cadastro de contatos</p><br></td>
   </tr>
  </table><br><br>
  <form id="form1">
   
   <label for="nome">Nome*:</label>
   <input id="nome" type="text" maxlength="50" name="nome"/><br><br><br>
   
   <label for="email">E-mail*:</label>
   <input id="email" type="text" name="email"/><br><br><br>
   
   <label for="nasci">Data Nascimento*:</label>
   <input id="nasci" type="date" name="nasci" min="1900-01-01" max="2019-06-30"/><br><br><br>
   
   <label for="cpf">CPF*:</label>
   <input id="cpf" value="11122233355" maxlength="11" type="int" name="cpf"/><label>(xxx.xxx.xxx-xx)</label><br><br><br>
   
   <label for="cidade">Cidade:</label>
   <input id="cidade" type="text" name="cidade"/><br><br><br>
   
   <label for="estado">Estado:</label>
   <select for="estado" type="int" name="estado">
    <option>Selecione</option>
    <option>AC</option>
    <option>AL</option>
    <option>...</option>
   </select><br><br><br>
   
   <label for="endereco">Endereco:</label>
   <input id="endereco" type="text" name="endereco"/><br><br><br>
  </form>
  
  <button width=35 height=25 title="Cadastrar" onclick="Cadastrar()">Cadastrar</button>
  <button width=35 height=25 title="Limpar" onclick="Limpar()">Limpar</button><br><br>
  
  <hr><br><br><br>
  
  <table id="tabela" width="400" border="1" align="left">
   <tr bgcolor="ff6600">
    <td>Nome:</td>
    <td>Email:</td>
    <td>Data Nascimento:</td>
    <td>CPF:</td>
    <td>Cidade:</td>
    <td>Estado:</td>
    <td>Endereco:</td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: tentei aqui, até alterei de leve um detalhe e outro, acabou não dando certo também, mas agradeço, vou ver o que posso fazer para resolver

Comment: Por nada, para alterar a cor é assim, se tiver outra dúvida e possa ajudar, estamos por aqui. Abs